# How to redirect to new view after facebook authentication in ios

Tags: objective-c, facebook, redirect

I am implementing facebook login in my ios app using FBLoginUIControlSample tutorial.I have implemented login through facebook successfully but the problem is after login control reaches to same View controller and Login button becomes logout. But in my application user has to be redirected to separate viewcontroller after successfully logged in. Then in a new viewcontroller I need to display welcome with username.

I have used this tutorial

https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-howtos/tree/master/FBLoginUIControlSample/FBLoginUIControlSample
can anyone help me in this regard please... I spent lot of time on it but I could not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about your app architecture. You probably want to use some kind of mediator to handle view controllers.

But if you just want to show welcome view (view controller) for now, try this.

In AppDelegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [FBProfilePictureView class];

     LoginUIViewController *loginUIViewController = [[LoginUIViewController alloc] init];
     UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:loginUIViewController];

     [[self window] setRootViewController: navigationController];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Then

In LoginViewController

```
- (void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView {

WelcomeViewController *welcomeViewController = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController: welcomeViewController animated: YES];
```

}

Now you can have welcome view controller in the navigation stack but again this is not good in long term because Login view controller is rootviewcontroller of your application even after logged in.  Hope this gives you good starting point. =)